# JQuery - Cycle a class with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I've a list wit below structure

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li class='active'> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
    <li> c </li>    
    <li> d </li>
    <li> e </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to change the class 'active' of li's in a cycling manner
Here is the script I'm working with. issue is it either adds the class *active* to all li's or removes the class *active* from all li's

```
      toggleSlide = function(){
          $("#slider ul li").each(function(index) {
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){

              $("#slider ul li").removeClass('active');
              $(this).next().addClass('active'));
              //lis = $("#slider ul li")
              //$(lis[(index+1)%lis.length]).addClass('active');
            }
          });
        }
   setInterval(toggleSlide, 5000);​
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can greatly simplify this with [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) and [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) since elements from [`.add()`](http://[%60.add()%60][1]) are turned in document order, it would look like this:

```
var toggleSlide = function(){
  $("#slider li.active").removeClass()
   .next().add("#slider li:first").last().addClass("active");
}
setInterval(toggleSlide, 5000);
```

[You can test it here (1000ms duration for the demo)](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/y9h5q/)

How this works is it takes the next `<li>` *if* there is one, then adds the first one as well, by using [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) (since they're in document order) we'll get the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) one *if* it's there, otherwise the set only contains one element, the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) `<li>`, and we're back to the beginning.

Comment: Very clever!  I hadn't run across .add() before, but I've gotta try it out now.

Comment: Thanks. This saved me some time.

Answer (score 2):

This should work a bit better:

```
toggleSlide = function() {    
    var $active = $('#slider ul li.active');
    if($active.length == 0) {
        $active = $('#slider ul li:first');
    }
    $active.removeClass('active');
    if($active.next('li').length > 0) {
        $active.next('li').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#slider ul li:first').addClass('active');
    }
}
setInterval(toggleSlide, 5000);​
```

You don't need the `.each()` loop and that's what was causing your issues. You only need to work on the current active element.

Live example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/MS5DV/

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for something far simpler

```
toggleSlide = function() {
    var active = $("#slider ul li.active");
    var next   = active.next();
    if (next.length === 0) {
        next = $('#slider ul li:first');
    }

    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
}
setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HyRYC/1/

Basically, find the active item and save it to a local var.  Then find the item after it and save that too.  Now if the last one is active, then `next()` will return a jQuery object with no matches, meaning it has a length of zero.  In that case, find the first item to be our `next`.

No we simply remove the `active` class from the current active item, and add it to our next one.

Comment: @Mithun - there's no need for the extra check...empty jQuery collections won't error, see my even shorter answer using this.

Comment: I completely agree that @Nick's answer is shorter, but I find @Squeegy's to be more readable.  Then again, I'm still coming up to speed on jQuery so maybe it's a matter of experience.