# JQuery - Cycle a class with timer and load remote content

Tags: jquery

I have look at the code below 
( // [JQuery - Cycle a class with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553204/jquery-cycle-a-class-with-timer))

and it runs nicely while change the color of the active class with the the updated content from time13.php
I would like be able to send and id to the remote file ( ie : get_inventory.php?o='+id  , id is the id-number of my items in my inventory
that change very rapidly) 
 , and put the content into the class. this way I would be able to give update inventory to the users.

any help would be appreciated

```
li.active {
    color: #f00;
}
```

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553204/jquery-cycle-a-class-with-timer

toggleSlide = function() {
    var active = $("#slider ul li.active");
    var next   = active.next();
    if (next.length === 0) {
        next = $('#slider ul li:first');
    }

    active.removeClass('active');
    // with affects next.fadeOut('slow').addClass('active').load('time13.php').fadeIn('slow');
 next.addClass('active').load('time13.php').fadeIn('slow');
}
setInterval(toggleSlide, 2000);
```

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li class='active'> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
    <li> c </li>    
    <li> d </li>
    <li> e </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When your inventory items change, do you have code that adds new <li> elements?  If not, by what means could your page be aware of the change in inventory items/size?

Answer (score 0):

I would use ajax to call the data then put the content of what you are trying to extract from the php file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "time13.php",    
  success: function(data) {
    $('li.active').html(data);

  },
    error: function(){
    alert('There was a error');
    }
});  
});
```